# Получить доступ к контролам IE для проверки полей ввода

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, плагин

Есть необходимость проверять поля ввода в Internet Explorer на корректность ввода. Другими словами, написать плагин.
Язык для этих целей выбрал C#, более менее подобрался к структуре документа, но получить доступ к контролам и менять тамошнюю информацию так и не получилось.
Может подскажете, где можно почитать содержательную инфу на эту тему? Перерыл нмого как русскоязычных, так и буржуйских сайтов, поэтому желательно предоставлять ссылки с конструктивной инфой.

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/WYSIWYG_netHTML2.aspx). В целом, это же требуется для разработки WYSIWYG html-редакторов, таких продуктов под .NET довольно много, можно их посмотреть.